# How to use Last-Modified header with Django Rest Framework ViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have following Django Rest Framework's ViewSet:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response


class SubscriptionViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        data = {'user_count': get_user_model().objects.count()}
        return Response(data)
```

How to use it together with [`last_modified`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/conditional-view-processing/#shortcuts-for-only-computing-one-value) decorator from Django? Or how to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked package mentioned by @Makarand Bauskar. However I wasn't satisfied. It's not active and it uses custom way how to work/deal with Last-Modified header. So I decided to create new package [django-rest-framework-condition](https://github.com/jozo/django-rest-framework-condition) that does:

1. Re-uses implementation from Django

   - it will get fixes from Django
   - you can use it same way as described in Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/conditional-view-processing/)
2. Provides both @last_modified and @etag decorator

To install it:

```
pip install django-rest-framework-condition
```

Usage:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_condition import last_modified


def my_last_modified(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return datetime(2019, 1, 1)


class SubscriptionViewSet(ViewSet):
    @last_modified(my_last_modified)
    def list(self, request):
        data = {'user_count': get_user_model().objects.count()}
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

@jozo,

You can check the https://github.com/jatir/django-rest-framework-last-modified django app to use the Last-Modified

Edit:

you can check the example in the test directory
https://github.com/jatir/django-rest-framework-last-modified/blob/master/tests/views.py#L14

Comment: Can you provide a code example how to use it with ViewSet?